# Wordpress Nested comment Form

Tags: wordpress, comments

Can some one suggest me how to populate nested comment form (i.e. reply to comments) for wordpress?

I have placed below code for reply:

```
<?php
echo get_comment_reply_link();
?>
```

But I am unable to see any reply link. Kindly suggest how I can place the reply link and open the reply box.

Comment: Seems you forgot to paste your code but only wrote the headline.. Please correct your question asap.. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but there's no code in your previous post :-/
Comments are out of the box feature in WordPress...